# In jmeter Can number of requests change for 2 different test runs of the same script? if so why does this happen?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a jmeter script and I ran it twice with a gap of few days. I see that in the results of the tests the number of requests to the server changed. What could be the possible reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your JMeter test for a defined time frame, i.e. using "Scheduler" section of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

[image]

or using a [Custom Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) like [Ultimate Thread Group or Stepping Thread Group](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420305-How-To-Configure-Ultimate-Stepping-Thread-Groups-Scenario-Legacy-JMeter-Test--How-To-Configure-UltimateStepping-Thread-Groups-Scenario-(Legacy-JMeter-Test)) the number of Samplers may vary depending on your application **response time**, like:

- higher response time -> less samplers
- lower response time -> more samplers

So pay attention to the average response time, most probably you will be able to determine the correlation. Also inspect other [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) to get the bigger picture